# Best way to concatenate command line args

Tags: c++, char, concatenation, command-line-arguments, strlen

I have `optind` pointing to my first non-switch argument. There can be any number of arguments total. I need to concatenate the remaining args into a `char*`. I have a loop that goes from `arg[optind]` to `arg[argc-1]` and gets the (length + 1) of each (one for spaces between args and one for `'\0'` at the end: `totalLen += strlen(arg[i]) + 1`. Once I have the length though what is the best route to use to concatenate the args through another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and it's [`operator +=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) and loop through `argv[]` and add the parameters to the string.

```
std::string non_switch;
for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    non_switch += argv[i];
```

Comment: Quick somewhat related question: if my program call is: `myProg.o -a -b foo=bar stack -overflow` would `optind` point to `foo=bar` still? Or would the `-overflow` throw that off? I want to be able to call other programs and their args as well, hence the need for concatenation.

Comment: That I do not know.  I was just using `optind` as the index of the first non switch argument but I have not used it.